# How to grep and copy files with spaces in their names

Tags: shell, grep, xargs, cp

I have some files with spaces in their names. I want to pick all the files containing a specific text, and copy those files to another directory. I can use `grep` to do the first part, but got stuck piping the file name list to `cp`. `cp` always slices the file names according to the spaces. I've tried `xargs --null`, and that didn't do me good. Any practical solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `--null` options for both `grep` and `xargs`:

```
grep --null --files-with-matches 'word' * | xargs --null cp -t "$target_dir"
```

The `--null` options cause the commands to terminate the filenames with a zero byte instead of newlines.